# Using maxima to plot a function f(x)=(-(x^3+6*x^2-18*x))/(4*(x^2+2)); keeps saying nothing to plot

Tags: maxima

Using maxima to plot a function f(x)=(-(x^3+6*x^2-18*x))/(4*(x^2+2)); keeps saying this;

plot2d: expression evaluates to non-numeric value everywhere in plotting range.
plot2d: nothing to plot.

I have tried tons of x and y values. Thanks

Comment: It's easier for other people to help if you tell exactly what you entered. For what it's worth.

Answer (score 3):

What have you tried? The following works:

```maxima
f(x) := (-(x^3+6*x^2-18*x))/(4*(x^2+2));
plot2d(f, [x, -5, 5]);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you, its now working! not sure why it wasn't. I need to find the local maximum, so have differentiated but not sure what to do next. do you have any idea please?

Comment: @nshepherd851: If this answer solved your question, you should accept it. For finding roots of functions, you could use the `find_root` function.